# issue with character controller collider in a c# unity 3d game

Tags: unity-game-engine, c#-4.0

I'm having a peculiar issue with my **character controller collider**. in the image provided the controller SHOULD fall down the side of this cube object, yet it "floats" or "hangs" on the corner which isn't a detrimental problem, but is something I'd like to fix now rather than later, any ideas?
[image of the controller statically floating on the edge of a cube object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpkLN.png)

I initially thought this issue may of been caused by incorrect properties within the controller, however after experimenting with the values the issue has not be resolved. I even tried ray casting to determine whether the controller is actively colliding with an object, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is**
it seems that the problem isn't directly on the collider but rather on the material you're using (which in this case, none)

**Solution**
from your project's asset, right-click and select create -> Physic material. From that physic Material, set the both Dynamic and Static friction to zero, then just draw that physic material to the game object. you can also adjust the friction depends on your needs

Comment: i've made the physics material as suggested, and set both the dynamic and static friction to 0. however, where exactly does this material go? drawing onto my character controller game object has no effect, with the same outcome for my graphics, also.

Comment: Add it on your collider, there should be a material variable there

Answer (score 0):

Character Controller has a skin width. Its an extra layer of collider which may cause this. Also check if the collider is within the capsule bounds. You can check out this article on [Unity Character Controller](https://vionixstudio.com/2022/09/19/unity-character-controller/) for more details.